# ErrorException in PlaceController.php line 101: Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5.1*

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a page where an user can put some data and save or post it. But when I try to visit my place adding url I get an error "ErrorException in PlaceController.php line 101: Trying to get property of non-object"

My Route:

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/','FrontView@index');
Route::get('/placesbydiv','FrontView@placesByDiv');
Route::get('/placesbydist','FrontView@placesByDist');


Route::get('/blog',['as' => 'blog', 'uses' => 'PostController@blog']);

//authentication
Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

// check for logged in user
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
 // show new post form
 Route::get('new-post','PostController@create');
 // save new post
 Route::post('new-post','PostController@store');
 // edit post form
 Route::get('edit/{slug}','PostController@edit');
 // update post
 Route::post('update','PostController@update');
 // delete post
 Route::get('delete/{id}','PostController@destroy');
 // display user's all posts
 Route::get('my-all-posts','UserController@user_posts_all');
 // display user's drafts
 Route::get('my-drafts','UserController@user_posts_draft');
 // add comment
 Route::post('comment/add','CommentController@store');
 // delete comment
 Route::post('comment/delete/{id}','CommentController@distroy');
});

//users profile
Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@profile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

// display list of posts
Route::get('user/{id}/posts','UserController@user_posts')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
// display list of posts by category
Route::get('category/{id}/posts','UserController@category_posts')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

// display single post
Route::get('/{slug}',['as' => 'post', 'uses' => 'PostController@show'])->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+');




//Places

Route::get('/place',['as' => 'place', 'uses' => 'PlaceController@place']);

// check for logged in user
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
 // show new post form
 Route::get('new-place','PlaceController@create');
 // save new post
 Route::post('new-place','PlaceController@store');
 // edit post form
 Route::get('edit/{slug}','PlaceController@edit');
 // update post
 Route::post('update','PlaceController@update');
 // delete post
 Route::get('delete/{id}','PlaceController@destroy');
 // display user's all posts
 Route::get('my-all-places','UserController@user_places_all');
 // display user's drafts
 Route::get('my-places-drafts','UserController@user_places_draft');
 // add comment
 //Route::post('comment/add','CommentController@store');
 // delete comment
 //Route::post('comment/delete/{id}','CommentController@distroy');
});
//users profile
//Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@profile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
// display list of posts
Route::get('user/{id}/places','UserController@user_places')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
// display single post
Route::get('/{slug}',['as' => 'place', 'uses' => 'PlaceController@show'])->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+');
```

My Place controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Places;
use App\User;
use App\Div;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\PlaceFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home', array('page' => 'home'));
    }

    public function place(Request $request){
         //fetch 5 posts from database which are active and latest
        $places = Places::where('active',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc');
        //page heading
        $title = 'দর্শনীয় স্থান';
        $search_key = $request->input('body');
        if(!empty('$search_key')){
            $places->where('body','LIKE','%'.$search_key.'%');
        }
        $places = $places->paginate(5);
        //return home.blade.php template from resources/views folder
        return view('place')->withPlaces($places)->withTitle($title);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // if user can post i.e. user is admin or author
        if($request->user()->can_post())
        {
          $divs = \DB::table('divs')->lists('div', 'id');
          return view('places.create')->with('divs', $divs);
        }    
        else 
        {
          return redirect('/')->withErrors('You have not sufficient permissions for writing post');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(PlaceFormRequest $request)
    {
        $place = new Places();
        $place->title = $request->get('title');
        $place->url = $request->get('url');
        $place->location = $request->get('location');
        $place->gmap_location = $request->get('gmap_location');
        $place->slug = $place->url;
        $place->body = $request->get('body');
        //$post->slug = str_slug($post->title);
       // $place->author_id = $request->user()->id;
        $place->div_id = $request->get('div');
        $place->source_url = $request->get('source_url');
        if($request->has('save'))
        {
          $place->active = 0;
          $message = 'Place saved successfully';            
        }            
        else 
        {
          $place->active = 1;
          $message = 'Place added successfully';
        }
        $place->save();
        return redirect('edit/'.$place->slug)->withMessage($message);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $place = Places::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        $div = \DB::table('divs')->where('id',$place->div_id)->first(); **//THIS IS THE ERROR LINE**
        if(!$place)
        {
           return redirect('/')->withErrors('requested page not found');
        }
    //    $comments = $post->comments;
        return view('places.show')->withPlace($place)->withDiv($div);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request,$slug)
    {
        $place = Places::where('slug',$slug)->first();
        if($place && ($request->user()->can_post() || $request->user()->is_admin()))
          return view('places.edit')->with('place',$place);
        return redirect('/')->withErrors('you have not sufficient permissions');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $place_id = $request->input('place_id');
        $place = Places::find($place_id);
        if($place && ($request->user()->can_post() || $request->user()->is_admin()))
        {
          $title = $request->input('title');
          $slug = str_slug($title);
          $duplicate = Places::where('slug',$slug)->first();
          if($duplicate)
          {
            if($duplicate->id != $place_id)
            {
              return redirect('edit/'.$place->slug)->withErrors('Title already exists.')->withInput();
            }
            else 
            {
              $place->slug = $slug;
            }
          }
          $place->title = $title;
            $place->location = $request->get('location');
            $place->gmap_location = $request->get('gmap_location');
            $place->body = $request->input('body');
            $place->source_url = $request->get('source_url');
          if($request->has('save'))
          {
            $place->active = 0;
            $message = 'Place saved successfully';
            $landing = 'edit/'.$place->slug;
          }            
          else {
            $place->active = 1;
            $message = 'Place updated successfully';
            $landing = $place->slug;
          }
          $place->save();
               return redirect($landing)->withMessage($message);
        }
        else
        {
          return redirect('/')->withErrors('you have not sufficient permissions');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $place = Places::find($id);
        if($place && ($request->user()->is_admin()))
        {
          $place->delete();
          $data['message'] = 'Place deleted Successfully';
        }
        else 
        {
          $data['errors'] = 'Invalid Operation. You have not sufficient permissions';
        }
        return redirect('/')->with($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried to `dd` this `$place->div_id` ?

Comment: In my places table there is a field named div_id. I am trying to compare that one with id of divs table.

Comment: Thanks All. I figured out my problem. In my route I used 2 middlewer, but there is needed only one.

Comment: glad you sort it out. however i suggest you fence `$place->div_id` just like answer by @mshaps. it is true it might returns null instead of expected model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check for `if(!$place)` belongs before you use `$place->div_id`.

It's possible that `$place = Places::where('slug',$slug)->first();` is not returning a model.